# Mongodb index built failed

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I have a MongoDB with around 80k documents, each one is an entry with `title`, `body_text`, etc. I want to do `FullTextSearch`, for which reason I created a text index with the command:

```
db.getCollection('arquivo_entry').createIndex({title:"text",body_text:"text"},{ weights:{title:2,body_text:1}},{default_language:"portuguese"})
```

The index building failed because of it ran out of memory and it killed the job that had mongodb running. This is in the log:

> 2018-03-22T14:58:12.017+0000 I -        [initandlisten]   Index Build: 2500/86187 2%
>
> 2018-03-22T14:58:15.028+0000 I -        [initandlisten]  Index Build: 6900/86187 8%
>
> 2018-03-22T14:58:18.012+0000 I -        [initandlisten]   Index Build: 12400/86187 14%
>
> 2018-03-22T14:58:21.065+0000 I -        [initandlisten]   Index Build: 17300/86187 20%
>
> 2018-03-22T14:58:24.047+0000 I -        [initandlisten]   Index Build: 22500/86187 26%
>
> 2018-03-22T14:58:27.043+0000 I -        [initandlisten]   Index Build: 28600/86187 33%
>
> 2018-03-22T14:58:30.013+0000 I -        [initandlisten]   Index Build: 34000/86187 39%
>
> 2018-03-22T14:58:32.478+0000 F -        [initandlisten] out of memory.

And the problem now is that I'm not able to delete the index and each time I try to launch the database it starts to rebuild the index automatically. Additionally, I'm not able to start a mongodb shell. It gives me the following error:

> MongoDB shell version v3.6.3 connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
>
> 2018-03-22T15:08:38.688+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
>
> 2018-03-22T15:08:38.688+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
>
> connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13 @(connect):1:6
>
> exception: connect failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start the database with [--noIndexBuildRetry](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod-noindexbuildretry) option, drop the text index, and restart the database as usual.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It worked. Do you have any advice about the alternative way to build the text search index?

Comment: Not really. There were similar issues in v3.0 https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17834?jql=text%20~%20%22%5C%22out%20of%20memory%5C%22%20createIndex%22, so if you can reliable reproduce it, please submit a new bug report.